# Looking for a data transformation solution (casting on complex data) in R

Tags: r, transform

Facing a problem with Purchase Order, Goods Receipt and Invoice data at work. The problem with the current data (with R code below) is that it segments a PO journey into two lines according to MD.Doc.Type.

```
PO.Document.Number<-c("Doc1","Doc1","Doc2","Doc2")
PO.Document.date<-c("12.01.2016","12.01.2016","03.01.2016","03.01.2016")
PO.Vendor<-c("200001","200001","200002","200002")
PO.Vendor.Name<-c("Vendor1","Vendor1","Vendor2","Vendor2")
BuyerCode<-c("G01","G01","G02","G02")
MD.Doc.Number<-c("500087","510035","500099","510050")
MD.Doc.Type<-c("GR","INV","GR","INV")
MD.Posting.Date<-c("04.03.2016","04.03.2016","09.03.2016","15.03.2016")
MD.Amount<-c("-67.5","80","-420.39","-420.29")
df<-data.frame(PO.Document.Number,PO.Document.date,PO.Vendor,PO.Vendor.Name,BuyerCode,MD.Doc.Number,MD.Doc.Type,MD.Posting.Date,MD.Amount)
rm(list=ls(-df))
```

I need to consolidate them into a single line for each PO, as below (consolidate 4 rows into 2 rows). The first two rows and last two rows in original data contains the same PO information (PO.Numb, Date, Vendor etc). In the transformation, the df "Posting.Date" becomes "GR Posting Date" or "INV Posting Date" depending on the value in "MD.Doc.Type" in df1, and similarly for "MD.Amount" and "Doc.Number".

```
PO-Document Number  PO-Document date    PO-Vendor   PO-Vendor-Name  BuyerCode   GR Number   GR Posting Date GR-Amount   Inv Number  Inv Posting Date    Inv Amount
Doc1    12.01.2016  200001  Vendor1 G01 500087  04.03.2016  -67.5   510035  04.03.2016  80
Doc2    03.01.2016  200002  Vendor2 G02 500099  09.03.2016  -420.39 510050  15.03.2016  -420.29
```

I've tried this so far:

```
df1<-cast(data=df, PO.Document.Number+PO.Document.date+PO.Vendor+PO.Vendor.Name+BuyerCode+MD.Doc.Number+MD.Posting.Date ~ MD.Doc.Type)
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bring[ing] them back into a single line". An example of your outcome would be preferred.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion @Adam, I've edited the post, hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider multiple dcasts binded to a distinct dataframe:

```
library(reshape2)

...

# FIXED COLUMNS
fixdf <- unique(df[c('PO.Document.Number', 'PO.Document.date',
                     'PO.Vendor', 'PO.Vendor.Name', 'BuyerCode')])

# CASTED COLUMNS
finaldf <- cbind(fixdf,
                 dcast(df, PO.Document.Number ~ MD.Doc.Type,
                      value.var = 'MD.Doc.Number')[,2:3],
                 dcast(df, PO.Document.Number ~ MD.Doc.Type,
                       value.var = 'MD.Posting.Date')[,2:3],
                 dcast(df, PO.Document.Number ~ MD.Doc.Type,
                       value.var = 'MD.Amount')[,2:3])

# RENAMING CASTED COLUMNS
names(finaldf)[6:11] <- c('GR Number', 'Inv Number',
                          'GR Posting.Date', 'Inv Posting.Date',
                          'GR Amount', 'Inv Amount')

#  PO.Document.Number PO.Document.date PO.Vendor PO.Vendor.Name BuyerCode
# 1              Doc1       12.01.2016    200001        Vendor1      G01
# 2              Doc2       03.01.2016    200002        Vendor2      G02
#   GR Number Inv Number GR Posting.Date Inv Posting.Date  GR Amount Inv Amount
# 1    500087     510035      04.03.2016       04.03.2016      -67.5         80
# 2    500099     510050      09.03.2016       15.03.2016    -420.39    -420.29
```

Comment: cbind + dcast works perfectly for my problem. thank you so much!

Comment: Great to hear! I'm glad to help.